# IOS Alamofire ssl pinning

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Hello folks I have problem on the ssl pinning certificate this is my code:

```
var afManager: SessionManager?

private func enableCertificatePinning() {

   let certificates = getCertificates()
      let trustPolicy = ServerTrustPolicy.pinCertificates(
          certificates: certificates,
          validateCertificateChain: true,
          validateHost: true)
      let trustPolicies = [ "domain": trustPolicy ]
      let policyManager = ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: trustPolicies)
      afManager = SessionManager(
          configuration: .default,
          serverTrustPolicyManager: policyManager
      )

    }




    private func getCertificates() -> [SecCertificate] {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "my certificate name", withExtension: "cer")!
        let localCertificate = try! Data(contentsOf: url) as CFData
        guard let certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, localCertificate)
           else { return [] }

        return [certificate]
    }
```

this code on charls don't block request

Comment: And what's the problem? Does `getCertificates()` return a non-empty array? Do you have a crash? What's wrong?

Comment: Hey Amjad, can you elaborate more on your question? A few tips: You can format your code better, provide error messages like a crash report or log messages. Being more specific helps other contributors to find the right answer for you.

Comment: ssl pinning not working always charls get all request data

Comment: have u find any solution